# Linux, changing the default FN-key functionality in xorg (key-bindings?)

Tags: linux, keyboard, xorg, keyboard-layout

So I bought a new keyboard from Logitech (TK820), without checking the key functionality beforehand.

It was a nasty surprise to find that on the top row, the multimedia keys (volume up, next track, and those) were the default, and to access `function keys` (F1-F12) one has to use the `FN` key. This is **highly** annoying, for example during coding when you want to search for next (F3), or you're closing the window (F4) etc.

So the question is, can I somehow modify the x.org configuration that the keys on top would go back to default functionality, and access to multimedia keys would be behind the FN key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the thread
[How to change Function (Fn) Key behavior on wireless Logitech keyboard](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285512/how-to-change-function-fn-key-behavior-on-wireless-logitech-keyboard).

It recommends using [Solaar](http://pwr.github.io/Solaar/) : A graphical utility that has the ability to configure the Fn key functionality on newer devices.

[image]

Comment: Note: It seems like Solaar has been retired.

Answer (score 3):

For other users who may stumble upon this question: Solaar didn't work with my (wired) Logitech K290, so I hacked together this small tool to restore the Fn-key-functionality to regular behaviour:

https://github.com/milgner/k290-fnkeyctl